# Why it shows always invalid credentials

Tags: laravel

I have a seeder so the users that can use the app can just run the seeder at the begining and have that administrator configured. The app only has one administrator. However, Im not undersanding why the login is not working properly it shows always that the credentials are invalid. Do you know what can be the issue?

```
class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
    {
        public function run()
        {
            $this->call([
                AdministratorSeeder::class,
            ]);
        }
    }
    class AdmininistratorSeeder extends Seeder
    {    public function run()
        {
            User::create(['name' => 'administrator', 'email' => config('services.administrator.key'), 'password' => bcrypt('password')]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not sure if it makes a difference, but have you tried `Hash::make('password')` instead?

Comment: did you create a mutator for the password attribute on that model by chance?

Comment: Thanks, but same issue! Its really strange in the db is ok the credentials are correct.

Comment: Yes I have this mutator:   public function setPasswordAttribute($password)
    {
        return $this->attributes['password'] = bcrypt($password);
    }

Comment: Well probably that was the issue it was doing the hashing twice? It seems that now is working!